# How to disable I18n lookups of Formtastic in activeadmin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, rails-i18n, formtastic

Using **activeadmin** in my app which by default uses `formtastic`, everything works

But the issue I am facing is that in activeadmin page take too much time to load and when I see logs it query on translation table for every label ,helper,hint, placeholder etc

Let say in edit form

```
f.input :place_id
```

then for this attribute there are 4 queries (I18n lookups)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `translations` WHERE `translations`.`locale` = 'en' AND (`key` IN ('formtastic.labels.used_car.edit.price') OR `key` LIKE 'formtastic.labels.used_car.edit.price.%')

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `translations` WHERE `translations`.`locale` = 'en' AND (`key` IN ('formtastic.labels.used_car.price') OR `key` LIKE 'formtastic.labels.used_car.price.%')

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `translations` WHERE `translations`.`locale` = 'en' AND (`key` IN ('helpers.label.used_car.edit.price') OR `key` LIKE 'helpers.label.used_car.edit.price.%')

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `translations` WHERE `translations`.`locale` = 'en' AND (`key` IN ('helpers.label.used_car.price') OR `key` LIKE 'helpers.label.used_car.price.%')
```

I want to remove all formtastic lookups so page load with speed.

I tried `Formtastic::FormBuilder.i18n_lookups_by_default = false`
 but nothing happens

Comment: did you try restarting the app after changing the config

Comment: yes....................

Comment: can you run a pry session in your request response cycle(or rails console), and get the value of `Formtastic::FormBuilder.i18n_lookups_by_default` ? This is just to make sure if the value is not being set from somewhere else.